# How to make a cat remember where he placed his toys?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, toys

My cat is 4 months old now. He always takes his toy off the bed, and once he doesn't want to play, he leaves his toy somewhere and just forgets it.

And when he wants to play with his toys, which I completely have no clue where they are, he meows loud at me, and even at night he would jump like a husky dog on my belly, blaming me why the toys don't automatically appear on the bed.

Is there a way to let my cat remember where he left his toy? Would intelligence improving toys help?

Comment: are you sure your cat realy forgets where the toys are,he might just want some attention from you.cats in general have a good memory but it can be a little selective,it is no need for him to remember where the toys are if you find them for him :) it is a little like children in the morning they ask mom do you remember where my....... are.

Comment: @trond hansen He would gradually start to find his toy if I keep not responding, but he seems really anxious and keep finding his toy under my quilt affirmatively. For additional information, he couldn't identify objects when he arrive home when he was 3 months old, he seems can't understand an object won't disappear when the object is behind something since he always stop chasing the toy when he can't see it, guessing because he was raised in a small rectangular cage without access of outer world before I brought him home.

Comment: One sure way of finding them is by walking around barefoot at night.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For you to get a good night's sleep and for your cat to find the toys you need to break the connection that the toys appear where you are.

This means you can only find the toys for your cat when he is not looking and for you to stay in bed if your cat wakes you to get his toys.

If and when your cat finds his toys and comes to you with them give him some attention and positive feedback; positive feedback is very effective when you want your cat to do something.

If you want a cat to stop doing something, negative feedback (as in telling the cat no) is not effective. It is better to give the cat attention when he does what you want.

Intelligence improving toys can be very helpful for stimulating your cat to learn new skills, but remember to change them after some time.

Your cat will learn to find his toys on his own. It will take time so you need to be patient and do not give in to your cat. Let him find the toys himself.